# Add a user variable to a link in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a script where a user types in a string that will be added to a link. I don't know much about Javascript or HTML so this example will be really weird.

```
var base = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";

var userInput = ReadForm();

button {


    <link>base + userInput</link>;

}
```

So lets say the user enters "dQw4w9WgXcQ" the link would be:

```
var base = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="

var user input = "dQw4w9WgXcQ"
```

Link= https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: 1. JavaScript identifiers can't contain spaces. 2. What's `button { <link>base + userInput</link>; }`?

Comment: [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) tag is not what you think it is.

Comment: @TJ At least it's not `<blink>` ;)

Comment: Create a html input field or a javascript window.prompt to get the users input. Add the input to the link. If the link is only a variable, you can just use + like you showed. If the link is inside a html <a> tag, you'll have to select that tag and update the href attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
  var link;
  var utubeLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
  link = utubeLink + $("#get").val();
  $("#display").text(link);
  console.log(link);
});

$("#go").click(function() {
  var utubeLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
  link = utubeLink + $("#get").val();
  window.open(link);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="get">
<button id="add">
  Add
</button>
<button id="go">
  Go
</button>
<br>
<br>
<text id="display"></text>
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fbpym61/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Could you help me to add this code to files? I can't get them to co operate correctly. I just need to use .html and .js files to use on my computer alt on dropbox...

Comment: could you send the files to my email in a zip or something? oliner.levay@hotmail.com

Comment: yeah. send it to your mail. Check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a textbox and a button in html:

```
<input type="text" id="url"/>
<input type="button" value="Create Url" onclick="createUrl()"/>
<p id="output"></p>
```

And in javascript on clicking of the button, just make the full url and then show it to user:

```
function createUrl() {
 var base = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "<a href='" + base + document.getElementById("url").value + "'>" + base + document.getElementById("url").value + "</a>";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could the link that you show to the user be click-able? Like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
 write a div

```
<div id="div1">

</div>
```

and the javascript for this would be

```
  var anchr= document.createElement("a");
    var base = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
    anchr.href = base+"somelink url";
    anchr.innerHTML='link Title';
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(anchr);
```

Please find it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/varada/Lmg2u3pd/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying, but check this code.

**JavaScript**

```
function goToVideo() {
  var base = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="; 
  var userInput = document.getElementById('video-id').value;
  window.location = base + userInput;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="video-id"/>
<button onClick="goToVideo()">Link</button>
```

`window.location` can be replaced by `return` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using **`prompt`**.

```js
var base = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
var plus = prompt("Enter Link:");
alert(base+plus);
```

Comment: Is there a way to redirect you to that url instead of just showing the user? That would be awesome /OP

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in Java.

If you already have the `Scanner` set-up (which it seems you have since you said `userInput`). If not please comment, I will edit it in.

If you just store YouTube base link ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=") in a String variable, then you can easily do this.

Just do the following:

```
String baseLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
baseLink = baseLink + userInput;
```

You can test if this works by doing:

```
System.out.println(baseLink);
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to make a script where a user types in a string that will be added to a link"* - please explain how to do that with Java without any client side script...

Comment: @TJ As I said, it looks like he already has the user input Scanner declared . That is why I just called the Scanner "userInput" and added it to the baseLink String. Whatever the user types will get added to the end of the base String. That is what he wanted. The Scanner has already been declared before this code.

Comment: First of all please understand that this question is not about Java. It's about responding to user interaction on a webpage. `JavaScript!=Java`